# famo.us - RenderController and draggable surfaces

Tags: famo.us

I have two surfaces.  One is draggable and one is 'full screen' (size: [undefined, undefined]).  I'd like to drag the first surface (yellow in my example) right and have the second (green)surface appear.  When I click on the green surface, I'd like show the first surface again back in the original starting point (center of screen).

I'd also like the green surface to be non-draggable.

I'm a famo.us novice, and any help is GREATLY appreciated!

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cjs123456/vfzy4j51/

```
    // the position state
    var position = [0, 0];

    // create a Sync to listen to mouse events
    var sync = new MouseSync();

    var renderController = new RenderController();

    var mySurface = new Surface({
        size: [350, 200],
        content: 'drag me right more than 100px to see other surface',
        properties: {
            backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (5 * 360 / 40) + ", 100%, 50%)",
            lineHeight: '200px',
            textAlign: 'center',
            cursor: 'pointer'
        }
    });

    // Surface provides events that the sync listens to
    mySurface.pipe(sync);

    // Syncs have `start`, `update` and `end` events. On `update` we increment the position state of the surface based
    // on the change in x- and y- displacements
    sync.on('update', function(data){
        position[0] += data.delta[0];
        position[1] += data.delta[1];
        console.log(data.position[0]);
        if (data.position[0] > 100) {
            console.log("FULL");
            renderController.show(fullSurface);
        }
    });

    // this modifier reads from the position state to create a translation Transform that is applied to the surface
    var positionModifier = new Modifier({
        transform : function(){
            return Transform.translate(position[0], position[1], 0);
        }
    });

    // a modifier that centers the surface
    var centerModifier = new Modifier({
        origin : [0.5, 0.5],
        align: [0.5, 0.5]
    });

    var fullSurface = new Surface({
        size: [undefined, undefined],
        content: 'Click me to show other surface',
        properties: {
            backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (9 * 360 / 40) + ", 100%, 50%)",
            lineHeight: '400px',
            textAlign: 'center'
        }
    });

    fullSurface.on("click", function() {
        renderController.show(mySurface);
    });

    renderController.show(mySurface);

    var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
    var node = mainContext.add(centerModifier).add(positionModifier);
    node.add(renderController);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than one way to solve this issue.

- **Control the dragging** of the render controller
- **Create separate render controller** and control views

Because your use case here is simple enough, I will show the **creating of a separate render controller**

Here is the **[jsFiddle Example of the Code](http://jsfiddle.net/25hzzgwy/)**

Create a background render controller

```js
var renderController = new RenderController();
var backRenderController = new RenderController();
```

Change the node to be the center modifier. Add our draggable to the node. Add the background controller to the node.

```js
var node = mainContext.add(centerModifier)
node.add(positionModifier).add(renderController);
node.add(backRenderController);
```

Control the draggable render contoller view (Line 42)

```js
    renderController.hide();
    backRenderController.show(fullSurface);
```

Clicking on the background will reset the position of the draggable back to the origin, hide the background and show the draggable again.

```js
    // Set draggable position back to the origin
    position = [0, 0];
    // Hide the back render element
    backRenderController.hide();
    // Show the draggable
    renderController.show(mySurface);
```

#### Full code:

```js
// the position state
var position = [0, 0];

// create a Sync to listen to mouse events
var sync = new MouseSync();

var renderController = new RenderController();
var backRenderController = new RenderController();

var mySurface = new Surface({
    size: [350, 200],
    content: 'drag me right more than 100px to see other surface',
    properties: {
        backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (5 * 360 / 40) + ", 100%, 50%)",
        lineHeight: '200px',
        textAlign: 'center',
        cursor: 'pointer'
    }
});

// Surface provides events that the sync listens to
mySurface.pipe(sync);

// Syncs have `start`, `update` and `end` events. On `update` we increment the position state of the surface based
// on the change in x- and y- displacements
sync.on('update', function (data) {
    position[0] += data.delta[0];
    position[1] += data.delta[1];
    console.log(data.position[0]);
    if (data.position[0] > 100) {
        console.log("FULL");
        renderController.hide();
        backRenderController.show(fullSurface);
    }
    //else {
    //    mySurface.setPosition([0,0,0], {
    //        curve: Easing.outBack,
    //        duration: 300
    //    });
    //}


});

// this modifier reads from the position state to create a translation Transform that is applied to the surface
var positionModifier = new Modifier({
    transform: function () {
        return Transform.translate(position[0], position[1], 0);
    }
});

// a modifier that centers the surface
var centerModifier = new Modifier({
    origin: [0.5, 0.5],
    align: [0.5, 0.5]
});

var fullSurface = new Surface({
    size: [undefined, undefined],
    content: 'Click me to show other surface',
    properties: {
        backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (9 * 360 / 40) + ", 100%, 50%)",
        lineHeight: '400px',
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
});

fullSurface.on("click", function () {
    // Set draggable position back to the origin
    position = [0, 0];
    // Hide the back render element
    backRenderController.hide();
    // Show the draggable
    renderController.show(mySurface);
});

//var node = mainContext.add(myModifier);
//node.add(draggable).add(surface);

renderController.show(mySurface);

var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
//mainContext.add(myModifier).add(draggable).add(renderController);

var node = mainContext.add(centerModifier)
node.add(positionModifier).add(renderController);
node.add(backRenderController);
```